# Git Revision Range shows warning

Tags: git, git-log

I want to know how many commits have been made in a particular time range so:

```
git shortlog -ns master@{2015-01-01}...master@{2015-12-31}
```

But git prompts with an warning message:

```
warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Sun, 18 Oct 2015 15:47:00 +0200.
```

If i do `git log >x.log` and take a look into the output i see also much other commits before that time point...

Can someone give me hint what is happening here or what the cause might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is since that this command fetch the data from the reflog and not from the branch.

Check your reflog and you will see that the last commit match the date of the error you get.

---

#### This is the answer you are looking for:

```
# print out shortlog in a time range
git shortlog master -sne --since="01 01 2015" --before="31 12 2015"
```

You can use any param you want with the short log.
In this sample i have used:

> #### -n / --numbered
>
> Sort output according to the number of commits per author instead of author alphabetic order.
>
> ### -s / --summary
>
> Suppress commit description and provide a commit count summary only.
>
> #### -e / --email
>
> Show the email address of each author.

Comment: Ah Ok...that helps. But doesn't mean the `--before "31 12 2015"...` to print information before the "31 12 2015" which would mean last information of "30 12 2015" ...so if i need the information incl. the 31.12.2015 to use `--before="01 01 2016"` ?

Comment: Yep. its up to the date that is marked, you got it right. it will be date older then the given date not including